# Can Site Visitors (NO edit permissions on site & document library ) share files with external users (anonymous users)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, external-users, sharing

Can Site Visitors (NO edit permissions on site & document library ) share files with external users (anonymous users) ?

I tried many options and it seems users with Edit rights only can share the documents via link to the anonymous users.

Is there any viable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many settings and found that there is no configuration allow site visitor users to share the documents. Check image below :

[image]

So, you must have edit permissions to share the file to user "Anyone with the link" option in the sharing popup.

I have generated all the sharing links using Power-Automate using admin rights and then on the dashboard for site visitors make them that link available to share with others.

Answer (score 0):

You may have settings set to Edit by default in your SharePoint admin center. you can change this to "View"

[image]

**#Updated answer**

It doesn't matter what permissions you have unless you have explicitly restricted them, even if you are logged as "Visitor" you can share "View only" link to document, follow the screenshot below you can see steps to share links with Anonymous users.
[image: visitors]

**#Update 2**
To enable Share with anyone, you need to enable "Site level" sharing. To do this, go to SPO admin center>> Active Sites >> Select the site where you want it enabled >> click sharing as in below screenshot >> Select Anyone >> Save

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks, from where I can find this settings, please?

Comment: SharePoint online admin center >> Polices >> Sharing

Comment: I know this settings but what I want to do is I want to allow users with read permissions to share a document and generate a link for external anonymous user. Is that possible with out edit rights?

Comment: Hi Akshay, I understood why you answered this. THis is correct for the setting permissions for the external users but I want Site visitors to share files with external users is that possible?

Comment: updated my answer above

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my concern is to make "Anyone with the link" (in the 3rd image you shared) enable for the site visitors group. Which I think not possible, right?

Comment: yes that is possible if you check my image to left i have displayed the user permissions, the user belongs to Visitor group

Comment: Btu you have "anyone with link" option disabled. I want to use that option with view rights.

Comment: updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior when approving in the dialog box.

[image]

As a workaround, **cancel** the dialog box and cahnge the permission under **Pending Requests**, find the request you want to update, click the ellipses... to open the menu> select the permission level you’d like to assign the user:

[image]

Reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-up-and-manage-access-requests-94b26e0b-2822-49d4-929a-8455698654b3

Comment: Thanks Julie! I updated the question description for more info!